# The relationship between dimensionality and space

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, quantum-gravity, spacetime-dimensions, theory-of-everything

The number dimensions defined by new theories keep going up. Is there a limit as to how many dimensions the universe can have?

Weird question. The curse of dimensionality in computer science illustrates how two data points get further apart as more dimensions are added to its analysis. Could a similar analogy be applied to the dimensions of the physical world?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/163958/2451 and links therein.